# Make a specific row bold based on query

Tags: html, ruby, redmine

I have a .html.erb file which is used to display a form on a website. (`Redmine`)

I need to make a **specific** row bold. When the tracker == Anomaly, the row must be bold.

[image: Sample of redmine]

```
<% if query.columns == Anomaly>
  make the text bold
```

but I think I have the wrong logic. How can I implement my idea?

I know what the ruby rows are processed in the following code. But I have no idea how to make a row bold based on a query.
**the current code**

```
<style>
.bolding {font-weight: bold;}
</style>

<tr id="issue-<%= issue.id %>" class="bolding hascontextmenu 
<%= cycle('odd', 'even') %> 

<%= issue.css_classes %> <%= level > 0 ? "idnt idnt-#{level}" : nil %>">

<td class="checkbox hide-when-print"><%= check_box_tag("ids[]", issue.id, false, :id => nil) %></td>

<td class="id"><%= link_to issue.id, :controller => 'issues', :action => 'show', :id => issue %></td>

<% query.columns.each do |column| %><%= content_tag 'td', column_content(column, issue), :class => column.css_classes %><% end %>

</tr>
```

Comment: This is unclear. What is "a column tracker"? Why are you testing the equality of `query.columns`? What is `query`?

Comment: @Deefour Sorry, I made some clarification,
I simply want to make the row bold when one of the column's string == Anomaly

I do not know what query is, I guessed it would make my code correct.

Comment: In your current code, you're applying `.bolding` to every row. Is this intended, or what you're trying to fix? I don't understand why you're checking `query.columns` against `"Anomoly"` still. Are you trying to find when `issue.tracker == "Anomoly"`? Or something else?

Comment: And by "column", do you mean **attribute** in an **ActiveRecord model** or **a table cell**? You've still also yet to show where `query` is defined and what `columns` is.

Comment: @Deefour Yes I am trying to do something like this issue.tracker == "Anomoly"

I don't know where query is defined. Isn't it a ruby function?

Comment: Please indent your code properly. `query` is not a ruby function, are you using a specific gem? Can you find `def query` somewhere in your codebase?

Comment: @iain I am trying to modify a webservice called Redmine, It is running Ruby on rails.
I do not know where is def query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the right way to do it

```
<tr id="issue-<%= issue.id %>" class="hascontextmenu <%= cycle('odd', 'even') %> <%= issue.css_classes %> <%= level > 0 ? "idnt idnt-#{level}" : nil %>" 
  <% if issue.tracker_id == 12 %> style="font-weight:bold" <% end %>
>

    <td class="checkbox hide-when-print"><%= check_box_tag("ids[]", issue.id, false, :id => nil) %></td>
    <td class="id"><%= link_to issue.id, :controller => 'issues', :action => 'show', :id => issue %></td>
        <% query.columns.each do |column| %><%= content_tag 'td', column_content(column, issue), :class => column.css_classes %><% end %>

</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

*You can avoid all of the confusion if you word your question clearly, and **provide all relevant details**. As @iain mentioned, `query` does not come from Rails, it comes from Redmine. **You should have mentioned you use Redmine in your question**.*

That said, it looks like `query` works with/from [this class](https://github.com/asoltys/redmine/blob/master/app/helpers/queries_helper.rb).

Each `column` in `query.columns` has a `name` attribute and a `value()` method *(among other things)*.

You can check for one of these `column`s in the `query.columns` collection having a `value` `"Anomoly"` and `name` `"Tracker"` like this.

```
query.columns.any? { |c| c.name.downcase == "tracker" && c.value(issue) == "Anomoly" }
```

You need to get the return value of this to conditionally apply the `bolding` class to your table row.

```
<%= apply_bolding = query.columns.any? { |c| c.name.downcase == "tracker" && c.value(issue) == "Anomoly" } %>
<tr id="issue-<%= issue.id %>" class="<%= apply_bolding ? "bolding" : nil %> hascontextmenu <%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't fully understand what you're trying to do, I used the code and it is not workiking. I should put an if statement somewhere, is that it?

Comment: I thought of this
<%= if @issue.tracker.name == 'Anomaly' %>

Comment: My answer is merely a guess as to what you're trying to do. I don't use Redmine and your question's still pretty unclear. If you want to provide more info in your Question as to how this "is not working" I'd be happy to take a look.